# How to execute a job X amount of minutes after instance is created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cron

I am using postgres with a project coded on rails.

Its a standard online store, when the customer clicks on "pay" an instance of the "transaction" model is created and the stock for that particular product or products is updated.

If this instance is not modified within 15 minutes (from a post request sent by the payment provider) i want an automated job to correct the stock inmediately, since we assume the transaction has been canceled for whatever reason.

I was looking into pg_cron but it is not compatible with heroku, pgagent seems to be a viable option but i have struggled to get ir running.

Since the job is not done at a specific time of the day, but only when the user creates a transaction, is it necessary to do this with a cron job?

What are your suggestions in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Active Job?

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job

e.g.

```
StockCleanupJob.set(wait: 20 minutes).perform_later(transaction)
```